# Click on button with selenium

Tags: python, parsing, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, bots

```
def get_source_html(url):
    executable_path = "D:\python\Новая папка\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"
    os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = executable_path

    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_extension('D:\python\Новая папка\CMEAKGJGGJDLCPNCIGGLOBPJBKABHMJL_1_18_47_0.crx')
    #chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach",True)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path="D:\python\Новая папка\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"
    )
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
    driver.maximize_window()


    try:
        driver.get(url=url)
        time.sleep(10)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[4]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a").click()
```

when I click on the button nothing happens, I entered its path through xpath. Below is the page code
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sz2yd.png). Can you help me with it

I tried to click on button by xpath

Comment: Can you share the URL of the website/application if it can be publicly accessible? For selenium to not click on a web element, there could be multiple reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an id for the button instead of xpath. The access on elements via xpath is slow and not so stable as an concret html id like:

```
<button id="buttonId">
Click me
</button>
```

Then use By.ID instead of By.XPATH:

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "buttonId").click()
```

Comment: But in there isn't <button id="buttonId">

Comment: you have to add the id to your button in the html file

Comment: @StefanLeith - That is not correct. You cannot modify the source code/HTML of application under test/website as per your convenience just so that you can automate it.

Answer (score 0):

instead XPATH use id like this :

```
  driver.find_element(By.id(""))
```